# Кодировка файла отправляемого по почте

Tags: delphi, кодировка, delphi-7

Подключаюсь к почте, помещаю содержимое письма в Memo1, а там краказябли. Может кто подсказать как избежать это?

```
IdPOP31.Host:='pop3.хостинг.ru';
IdPOP31.Port:=110;
IdPOP31.Username:='логин';
IdPOP31.Password:='пароль';
IdPOP31.Connect;
IdMessage1.Clear;
if IdPOP31.CheckMessages<1 then Break;
IdPOP31.Retrieve(1,IdMessage1);
Memo1.Clear;
Memo1.Lines:=(IdMessage1.MessageParts.Items[0] as TIdText).Body;
```

Comment: вот разберись что за [кракозябры][1]


  [1]: http://img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/full/%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-261417.png

Comment: Вот текст, если не ошибаюсь - под скрипт он не попадает(
{
Forum Notification: New Post in ьЛПОПНЙЛБ, ВЙЪОЕУ, РТЕДРТЙОЙНБФЕМШУФЧП : нБТЛПЧУЛЙЕ жПТХНЩ

Hello,

бЧФПЛПОФТБЛФ has just replied to the topic entitled - йЭЕН ЙОЧЕУФПТБ-ВЙЪОЕУ РБТФОЕТБ - in the ьЛПОПНЙЛБ, ВЙЪОЕУ, РТЕДРТЙОЙНБФЕМШУФЧП forum of нБТЛПЧУЛЙЕ жПТХНЩ.

This topic is located at http://izhevsk.ru/forummessage/71/4287775-0.html#m3264463
Here is what the user posted:

quote:Originally posted by Vall:

НЩ ОЕ УПВЙТБЕНУС ОБ ЖПТХНЕ ЮФП МЙВП РЙУБФШ


Б ЧПФ ЬФП РТБЧЙМШОП!!! МХЮЫЕ ВЩ ЧППВЭЕ ОЕЮЕЗП ОЕ РЙУБМЙ!)}

Comment: Это KOI8-R выведенная в Win-1251

Comment: Есть ли какой-нибудь метод перевода текстовой информации в необходимую кодировку?

@kot-da-vinci Вы не однократно помогали мне на данном форуме, указывали на мои ошибки, за что я Вам благодарен. Мне очень интересно, какой у Вас опыт программирования?

Comment: @АлександрЪ Скажем так, программированием "для себя" я занимался еще лет 10 назад. А работаю программистом уже почти 3 года.
Похоже в Delphi7 нет средств для перевода кодировок, придется изобретать велосипед :)
Вот здесь обсуждение твоей проблемы: http://www.delphimaster.net/view/2-1288068191
`CharSet` может быть пустым если кодировка в заголовках не указана или указана не в том месте. Например, в теме письма или в поле "кому".

Comment: @kot-da-vinci благодарю. На некоторых форумах писали, что у TIdMessage есть свойство convertpreamble, но Delphi 7 его у меня не распознает. Как вы считаете, это связано с версией Delphi?

@kot-da-vinci мне 22. Многие мои знакомые ушли в Web-программирование, а общаясь со мной неоднократно упоминают о превосходстве web-программирования и о том как сильно неудобен Delphi. Хотел бы поинтересоваться у Вас: на Ваш взгляд, логично ли вообще сравнивание этих языков программирования, если да, то какой стороне Вы придерживаетесь?

Comment: Это связано скорее с версией Indy компонент. На Delphi 7, вроде, можно было поставить Indy 10. А почему Вы выбрали Delphi 7? Delphi действительно неудобен в web-программировании :) Это инструменты для разных задач. Сравнивать их неправильно. Ну это как пассатижи и молоток. Если захотеть, то и пассатижами можно гвоздь забить :) Но Delphi 7 не самый удобный из Delphi, даже Delphi 2006 уже намного удобнее. Дальнейшие обсуждения, не относящиеся к вопросу, предлагаю перенести в личку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IdMessage1` наверняка должен содержать поле/метод которое скажет в какой кодировке текст письма, кодировка обычно указывается в служебных заголовках писем. Ну а дальше останется только преобразовать текст в нужную кодировку.

**UPD:**
`CharSet` может быть пустым если кодировка в заголовках не указана или указана не в том месте. Она может быть указана в теме письма или в поле "кому". Например, так:

> Subject: =?koi8-r?B?6c7Gz9LNwcPJ0Q==?=

Обсуждение этой проблемы [здесь](http://www.delphimaster.net/view/2-1288068191).

Comment: Совершенно верно! - IdMessage1.CharSet
Возвращает строку (string)
Поместил его в ShowMessage, но в сообщении ничего не отобразилось(

Comment: У класса `TIdMessage` есть метод `ProcessHeaders`.
*ProcessHeaders is a procedure that updates message properties based on header values in the message.*
Попробуйте перед проверкой поля `CharSet` выполнить `ProcessHeaders`.

Comment: IdMessage1.ProcessHeaders;
ShowMessage(IdMessage1.CharSet);
К сожалению, результат тот же(

Answer (score 0):

Я помнится просто в Uses нечто похожее на `StrUtils` или `Windows` (точно не скажу) писал и появлялись разные интересные функции, типа `OemToChar` и наоборот - помогало в похожих ситуациях. `StringList` на лету весь конвертировался в нужную кодировку.

http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=66815 - посмотри еще здесь, может и поможет.

Comment: На XE3 таких функций встроенных достаточно сейчас, подзабылась семерочка )))

Comment: Точно !!! StrUtils !!! Внутри этой библиотеки много строковых утилит и для кодировок, и для сравнения строк и для прочих со строками операций.